# python loop through a dictionary to see if values exist

Tags: python, dictionary

I am trying to loop though a python dictionary to see if values that I am getting from a csv file already exist in the dictionary, If the values do not exist I want to add them to the dictionary. then append this to a list.

I am getting the error list indices must be integers, not str.

example input

first name last name

john           smith

john           smith

example output

first_name john last name smith

user_list =[]

```
with open(input_path,'rU') as csvfile:
        reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)

for row in reader:

  if row['first_name'] not in user_dictionary['first_name'] and not in row['last_name'] not in user_dictionary['last_name']:
      user_dictionary = {

          'first_name':row['first_name'],
          'last_name':row['last_name']
            }
            user_list.append(user_dictionary)
```

Comment: Please explain your code. How is it failing. Provide a sample input, expected output and current error/bad output you are getting to clearly show where your problem exists.

Comment: In your first iteration - `user_dictionary` doesn't exist yet... In your subsequent iterations, `user_dictionary` refers to the last instance of it... Are you supposed to be checking against *all* dictionaries in the `user_list` ?

Comment: Your indentation also needs fixing; as posted, your `for` loop should exit immediately with an exception for trying to read a closed file (because the `for` loop is outside the `with` block).

Answer (score 0):

Currently, your code is creating a new dictionary on every iteration of the for-loop. If each value of the dictionary is a list, then you can append to that list via the key:

```
with open(input_path,'rU') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
user_dictionary = {"first_name":["name1, "name2", ...], "last_name":["name3", name4", ....]}
for row in reader:
    if row['first_name'] not in user_dictionary['first_name'] and not in row['last_name'] not in user_dictionary['last_name']:
       user_dictionary["first_name"].append(row['first_name'])
       user_dictionary['last_name'].append(row['last_name'])
```

Answer (score 0):

Generally, you can use a membership test (`x in y`) on [`dict.values()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.values) view to check if the value already exists in your dictionary.

However, if you are trying to add all unique users from your CSV file to a list of users, that has nothing to do with dictionary values testing, but a list membership testing.

Instead of iterating over the complete list each time for a slow membership check, you can use a [`set`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#set) that will contain "ids" of all users added to a list and enable a fast `O(n)` (amortized) time check:

```
with open(input_path,'rU') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)

user_list = []
user_set = set()
for row in reader:
    user_id = (row['first_name'], row['last_name'])
    if user_id not in user_set:
        user = {
            'first_name': row['first_name'],
            'last_name': row['last_name'],
            # something else ...
        }
        user_list.append(user)
        user_set.add(user_id)
```

Comment: If you really wanted... `user_list = [{'first_name': fn, 'last_name': ln} for fn, ln in {(row['first_name'], row['last_name']) for row in reader}]`...

Comment: That's a nice shortcut, but it makes harder (if not impossible) to add other attributes to `user` dict/list (other than first and last name).

Comment: Well, you can do `list({(row['first_name']: row['last_name']): row for row in reader}.values())` and make the values what you want there instead of the entire row - however, it'd retain the last occurrence of the key and not the first which may be important...

Comment: Yes, many options, if only OP could clarify what he wants exactly.. :)

Answer (score 0):

The error `"list indices must be integers, not str"` makes the problem clear: On the line that throws the error, you have a list that you think is a dict. You try to use a string as a key for it, and boom!

You don't give enough information to guess which dict it is: It could be `user_dictionary`, it could be that you're using `csv.reader` and not `csv.DictReader` as you say you do. It could even be something else-- there's no telling what else you left out of your code. But it's a list that you're using as if it's a dict.

Comment: sorry I thought I put this in when I edited my question the error is to do with the user dictionary

Comment: In the code you show you initialize it to a dict. But it seems initialize it to a list.

Comment: ... it seems **you first** initialize it to a list :-(